# How to refresh the view when global variable change

Tags: swiftui, view, global-variables

I have made a template restaurant app that works with 4 mainly views and switch between them with a costum TabBar.
To navigate along each view i embeded the parent page in a NavigationView and use NavigationLInk to redirect to child view.
To store the user's orderd food i used a global variable defined in a separate file

```swift
var itemsInCart:[FoodItem:Int] = [:]
```

I have configure a view where the user add the food with the quantity that he wants and save it in `itemsInCart` dictionary.`FoodItem` is a costum struct to store food informations, like name and other stuffs.
The problem is that I use one view to add to the dictionary with this code, `name` being the current struct's property `name` which store the name of the food

```swift
 .onTapGesture{
                        //add items to dict storage
                        itemsInCart[allFood[allFood.firstIndex(of:allFood.filter{$0.name==name}[0]) ?? 0]] = 
(itemsInCart[allFood[allFood.firstIndex(of:allFood.filter{$0.name==name}[0]) ?? 0]] ?? 0) + quantity
//                        print(itemsInCart)
                        
                        dismiss()
                        
                        
                        
                    }
```

Which searches for the index of the food with the same name, then searches for the item in the array `allFood` the incrementing the quanity.

When i switch to the `Cart` view to see all food that has been bought, using the global variable won't update my view right away.
In the `Cart` view i have put all items from the cart with two buttons to increment and decrement the quantity.But when I press them the view does not update.

I know this is happening because i dindn't use a `@State` property

My question is how can i pass a global variable across many structs that are in different files and update the view when it modify?

I have tried with `@StateObject` and it's awful for my needs because i have to modify all of my structs.

Comment: It does not work that way. SwiftUI views are updated ONLY by dynamic properties, ie State, StateObject, ObservedObject, etc. You need to rethink design - maybe with shared app state as ObservableObject containing that itemsInCart.

Comment: If you can Give me am example how I would do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A12299030+AppState